# Truthful assignment for facility allocation problems

Tags: mechanism-design, social-choice, dominant-strategy, congestion-games

We have the following **congestion game**. $n$ agents and $m$ facilities are positioned on the real line $\mathbb{R}$. The position of agent $i$ is denoted by $x_i\in \mathbb{R}$ and the location of facility $j$ is denoted by $\ell_j \in \mathbb{R}$. Each agent wants to patronize one and only one facility and get its service. That is, the *strategy set* of each agent is $[m]$. Each facility $j$ has a positive *building cost* $b_j>0$, which will be *equally* shared by its customers. Given a strategy profile $\mathbf{s}=\{s_1,\cdots,s_n\}$ and suppose $s_i=j$, the *cost* of agent $i$ is the sum of the distance between $i$ and facility $s_i$ and her share of the build cost of facility $j$. Formally, $$c_i(\mathbf{s})=|x_i-\ell_{j}|+\frac{b_{j}}{n_{j}}$$ where $n_{j}$ is the number of agents who choose facility $j$ in $\mathbf{s}$.

I'd like to consider the above game from the perspective of mechanism design. The position of each agent becomes her private information. Each agent is required to report her position to a mechanism $f$. Let $\mathbf{x}'=\{x_1', \cdots, x_n'\}$ be the reported position profile of agents.
The location and build cost of each facility is *publicly* known.
The mechanism outputs an assignment of agents to facilities, i.e., $f(\mathbf{x}',\mathbf{\ell}, \mathbf{b})=\mathbf{s}$, where $\mathbf{\ell}=\{\ell_1, \cdots,\ell_m\}$ and $\mathbf{b}=\{b_1,\cdots,b_m\}$ is the location profile and the build cost profile of facilities, respectively.
A mechanism $f$ is *truthful* if each agent minimizes her cost by reporting her real position. Formally, $f$ is truthful if and only if for any building cost profile $\mathbf{b}=\{b_1,\cdots,b_m\}$, any facility location profile $\mathbf{\ell}$, any agent location profile $\mathbf{x}$, any agent $i\in [n]$, any deviation $x_i'\in \mathbb{R}$, we have $c_i(f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{\ell}, \mathbf{b})) \le c_i(f(\mathbf{x}',\mathbf{\ell}, \mathbf{b}))$, where $ \mathbf{x}'= (x_i', \mathbf{x}_{-i})$ is obtained from $\mathbf{x}$ by replacing the position of agent $i$ with $x_i'$.

The goal is to design truthful mechanisms which also (approximately) minimize the total cost of agents.  Some restriction may also be enforeced to the mechanism, e.g., Pareto optimal and anonymous.
However, the only truthful mechanism I can imagine is to assignment all agents to a specific facility. The setting here is a little bit tricky since in standard mechanism setting the private information of an agent is her true preference over the facilities, while in our setting the private position only represent part of her preference over the facilities (the distance) while the second part (the share of building cost) is unknown. I was wondering the existence of any non-trivial truthful mechanisms.
I also appreciate any related literature on this topic, especially on truthful mechanism design with partial preference.

I think the setting may hit the barrier of the Gibbard-Sattherthwaite impossibility: For n agents and m facilities, there are $n^m$ possible assignments and each agent's preference over these assignments is expressed by her position. So basically the desired mechanism  is a social choice function for n voters and $n^m$ alternatives. The only problem is that whether there are restrictions on the preference domain since the preference over assignment is somehow hidden in the cost function. If the answer is no then the setting is dominated by GS impossibility.

Comment: Thinking in terms of $s : [n] \to [m]$ and its preimages, we have $n_j := \left| s^{-1} (j) \right|$.